# How do I use a dataframe object from another function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorization

I have 3 functions; one that processes a dataframe with 4 columns (MemberID, year, DSFS and DrugCount) and returns 3 dataframes categorized by year, a helper function that reformats year, and a third one that categorically recodes a dataframe based by year.

- How would I take a dataframe categorized by year as my input for the third function?
- I want to find the list of unique categories using `df['DSFS'].unique()`. What would I use as my `df`?

Sample of the csv file.

`MemberID          DSFS  DrugCount
2   61221204   2- 3 months          1
8   30786520   1- 2 months          1
11  28420460  10-11 months          1
12  11861003   4- 5 months          1
14  66905595   6- 7 months          4`

```
def process_DrugCount(drugcount):
    dc = pd.read_csv("DrugCount.csv")
    sub_map = {'1' : 1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7+' : 7}
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.map(sub_map)
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.astype(int)
    dc_grouped = dc.groupby(dc.Year, as_index=False)
    DrugCount_Y1 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y1')
    DrugCount_Y2 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y2')
    DrugCount_Y3 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y3')
    DrugCount_Y1.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    DrugCount_Y2.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    DrugCount_Y3.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return (DrugCount_Y1,DrugCount_Y2,DrugCount_Y3)

def replaceMonth(string):
    replace_map = {'0- 1 month' : "0_1", "1- 2 months": "1_2", "2- 3 months": "2_3", "4- 5 months": "4_5", "5- 6 months": "5_6", "6- 7 months": "6_7", "7- 8 months" : "7_8",\
                   "8- 9 months": "8_9", "9-10 months": "9_10", "10-11 months": "10_11", "11-12 months": "11_12"}
    a_new_string = string.map(replace_map)
    return a_new_string

def process_yearly_DrugCount(aframe):
    processed_frame = None
    dc = pd.read_csv("DrugCount.csv")
    sub_map = {'1' : 1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7+' : 7}
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.map(sub_map)
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.astype(int)
    dc_grouped = dc.groupby(dc.Year, as_index=False)
    DrugCount_Y1 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y1')
    DrugCount_Y1.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    # print DrugCount_Y1['DSFS'].unique
    return processed_frame
```

Comment: Can you add sample of `DrugCount.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Your example was not super clear to me, but here is a slightly different example based on the pandas docs which demonstrates some useful techniques:

It sounds like rather than using groupby you should use df.pivot_table to reshape into a multi-index.

E.g. try :

```
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3
def unpivot(frame):
    N, K = frame.shape
    data = {'value' : frame.values.ravel('F'),
            'variable' : np.asarray(frame.columns).repeat(N),
            'date' : np.tile(np.asarray(frame.index), K)}
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'variable', 'value'])

df = unpivot(tm.makeTimeDataFrame())
```

to make a test df, then compare df.head():

```
        date variable     value
0 2000-01-03        A -0.357495
1 2000-01-04        A  0.367520
2 2000-01-05        A  2.216699
3 2000-01-03        B -0.417521
4 2000-01-04        B -1.163966
```

with print df.pivot_table(index=("variable","date"))

```
                        value
variable date                
A        2000-01-03 -0.357495
        2000-01-04  0.367520
        2000-01-05  2.216699
B        2000-01-03 -0.417521
        2000-01-04 -1.163966
        2000-01-05 -0.774422
C        2000-01-03  0.560017
        2000-01-04  0.174880
        2000-01-05  0.625167
D        2000-01-03 -1.673194
        2000-01-04 -0.075789
        2000-01-05 -2.041236
```

You can then do df_pivoted.loc['A'] gives you :

```
            value
date                
2000-01-03 -0.357495
2000-01-04  0.367520
2000-01-05  2.216699
```

You can easily adapt this to your example using years. Its easier than using group by for this type of manipulation, and it keeps all the data in one dataframe (view).

You can also use value_counts to find all the values and their frequencies. So in my example:

```
df['variable'].value_counts()
```

will return a series:

```
D    3
B    3
C    3
A    3
Name: variable, dtype: int64
```

Here the index of that series is your list of unique values if I have understood correctly. so

```
list(df['variable'].value_counts().index)
```

Should give you what you want.